# whether the paper trail has a way to track the user activity based on a specific role

Tags: paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to use paper trail to track user activity in my application. i have set up the gem, followed the tutorial and made it work fine in my application..

but, when I test it as an ordinary user (as a guest user), paper trail also tracks this guest activity which the same model and controller...

Is there any way how to track the user activity based on role ?

i mean, i just want to track the activity of a specific role..

Need help..

[paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just want to track the activity of a specific [user] role

You can turn PaperTrail off in your controller. From the [documentation](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/#per-request):

> ### Turning PaperTrail Off
>
> #### Per Request
>
> Add a `paper_trail_enabled_for_controller` method to your controller.
>
> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
>   def paper_trail_enabled_for_controller
>     !(cool_user? || trustworthy?) # :) this part is up to you
>   end
> end
> ```

If that doesn't work, there are many other ways to turn PaperTrail on/off described the documentation.

Comment: no one working well in my case neither your way nor the documentation way,. :D
i wonder why?

the documentation said paper_trail enabled is "true" by the default. so i think i should make it "false" first.  so i tried to put this code `config.paper_trail.enabled = false` in the environment/development.rb, but the console said undifined method paper_trail when i running the server, neither too with the other ways, like put `widget.paper_trails_off!` in the class.
i still try to solve this one.. :D

Comment: does the `PaperTrail.enabled = false` only works on the test environment?

Comment: My one .. I have been fooled by my angular controller.. i put this `aper_trail_enabled_for_controller`..

i finally put it in my Api BaseController and it work perfectly...

thx mr Jared...